# Asignar element (htm) a variable (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Muy buenas tardes, bien nuevo en este foro, un gusto en saludar esta comunidad inteligente. Recientemente me estoy iniciando en la programación de aplicaciones, y estoy en un proyecto donde un equipo electrónico usa el web server para el envió de datos en una pagina alojada dentro de su memoria en formato HTML, JavaScript, CSS.

La integración esta funcionando perfectamente, salvo que se requiere representar los datos de   :="webdata".pres_1:   en una variable definida en JavaScript en el archivo bar_chart.js.

Podrían  ayudarme un poco ya que he definido las variables en JavaScript de la siguiente manera :

```
let get_pressure = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es asignar el valor leído de :="webdata".pres_1: en la posición 0 del array:

```
get_pressure[0] = :="webdata".pres_1:
```

El archivo de inicio HTML seria Home.html, el archivo de JavaScript es bar-chart.js, cargado previamente en el código de Home.html, el archivo de recepción de datos es plc_io.html donde solo tiene un código de recepción :="webdata".pres_1

[[image: Las barras son los datos de get_pressure]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO] recuerda hacer el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Veo que tu pregunta tiene muy poca información. Nombras algunos archivos adicionales pero no muestras que haces en cada uno de ellos. Tampoco es muy claro que significa `:="webdata".pres_1`. Estas usando algun tipo de sistema de templates?

Comment: Bueno estoy representando unas barras verticales en HTML, Javascript y CSS. En estos momentos no he logrado transformar ese dato :="webdata".pres_1 a una variable. el dato :="webdata".pres_1, es la forma en que el fabricante del equipo electrónico establece que deben cargarse esos datos en el HTML, no es un template